# How could I perform a search using a array file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to know how can I perform a concatenation "inside" a powershell array to run a command in windows and get a specific part of code. I produce the  code below but isn't works.

```
[string[]]$a = Get-Content -Path @("C:\users\me\file.txt")
foreach($name in $a){
    $b = "Get-Process | net user '$a' /do"
    Invoke-Expression $b | Select-String "Nome completo="
        }
```

Thanks for anyone who could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$name` to refer to the individual array items being iterated (`$a` refers to *the whole array*):

```
foreach($name in $a){
    Get-LocalUser $name |ForEach-Object FullName
}
```

Comment: @grn11 What error? Your original post made no mention of any error :)

Comment: when i use this command, i received a lot of errors like this: Get-LocalUser : Usuário 'user1' não encontrado.
No linha:3 caractere:6
+      Get-LocalUser $name | ForEach-Object FullName
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ('user1':String) [Get-LocalUse 
   r], UserNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UserNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetLo 
   calUserCommand                                                              I trying to make a search in a specific domain with the users in this array. Is this possible?